# DOMContentLoaded never fires inside a module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm confused regarding events not firing in a particular ES6 module loading scenario. Here is a Codepen project to support my examples:
https://codepen.io/fchristant/project/editor/AYQkGJ

Consider this very simple module **app.js**:

```
console.log('in module');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DCL:2');
});
```

I'm using dynamic ES6 imports from script tags in the head of the document:

```
<script>
  (async () => {
    const module = await import("./js/app.js");
    console.log('async done');
   })();
</script>
```

So, this calling code is a non-module (sync script) dynamically loading a module. Because it is in the head of the document and not async or defer, I expect it to run immediately, and to do so in a blocking way.

That's my expectation, yet not what is happening. In particular, the problem is that the event in the module is never fired. And it looks to be because it's too late to listen to it, the event has already happened. How can this be, given the blocking script in the head of the document? It looks to be non-blocking, yet I don't understand why.

To be clear, the discussion isn't whether this is a good idea or not, I'm above all interested in the conceptual answer of why this doesn't work. Or to rephrase the question: how can a non-module script dynamically load a module in a synchronous way?

Comment: If you want to load the script in a *synchronous* way, then you should just add it to the document in a `<script>` tag. The advantage of modules is that you can use different functions from other scripts in a single script by importing them and calling them there. In your case, your file is downloaded, but there is no exported function in your `app.js` script, so there is nothing to call or to use.

Comment: What should I export then? The code inside the module clearly is running, as "in module" is printed. Yet by the time it runs, domcontentloaded has already happened. I still don't have an answer as to why this is.

Comment: Importing your module asynchronously tells the browser that it should not wait for the module before emitting `DOMContentLoaded` event. This is almost the same as adding the `async` attribute to a `SCRIPT` tag. If you want your module to handle the `DOMContentLoaded` event - you should not use async importing.

Comment: `async` functions are non-blocking - so there is no "blocking script in the head"

Comment: You could put the `domcontentloaded` event listener in your main script and import your module when the event has occurred.

Comment: @IVOGELOV But there is no such thing as sync importing it, except from another module. Which in turn is async loaded. So there's no way for any code inside a module for this DOM event?

Answer (score 5):

Wait for the `domcontentloaded` event to happen in your `index.html` file. In the callback of the event import the module that you want to run whenever the event has fired.

```js
// app.js
export function start() {
  console.log('in module');
  console.log('DCL:2');
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async (event) => {
    const module = await import("./js/app.js");
    module.start();
    console.log('async done');
  });
</script>
```

Or if you don't need any modules and you simply want everything to load one after another before the DOM has been rendered, just use the traditional render-blocking `<script>` tags.

```
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log('module loaded');
</script>
```

Comment: This is not the question, this is a workaround and completely different solution. Which would work but not what I'm after. The question is how *inside* module code one can listen to this DOM event. The answer may very well be "you can't", but that seems weird. It's not a strange use case for a module to wait for particular dom events.

Comment: Consider this, your module is *asynchronously* loaded into the document with dynamic imports, no way around that. So if your DOM is huge and your connection fast then you might catch the `domcontentloaded` event just in time. But with a small DOM and slow connection, your module will probably always be too late. So you have a race condition. So yeah, it's not possible the way you want it.

Comment: And no, it's not strange for a module to handle an event like `domcontentloaded`, at least not when you use a module bundler which puts everything in a single file.

Comment: In my case app.js is a module itself, and the reason for that is that it imports its own modules, statically. A static import is only possible if app.js is a module too. Yet there seems to be no way to synchronously load any module, it looks plain impossible. Looks like you're right.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a helper function to check [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) and then either [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or run code immediately.

- `onDCL1()` can be used with a callback fn (A.1)
- `onDCL2()` is [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based

  - … traditional `.then()` chain (B.1)
  - … or `await` for it (C.1)

We can "fake" and dispatch our own [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) event and verify that `else` block works (A.2. , B.2. , C.2.)

```js
class App {
  static onDCL1(callback) {
    if (document.readyState !== 'loading')
      callback(`onDCL1 ➜ readyState: '${document.readyState}'`);
    else
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
        e => callback(`onDCL1 ➜ ... waited readyState: '${document.readyState}'`));
  }

  static onDCL2() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if (document.readyState !== 'loading')
        resolve(`onDCL2 ➜ readyState: '${document.readyState}'`);
      else
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
          e => resolve(`onDCL2 ➜ ... waited readyState: '${document.readyState}'`));
    });
  }
}

(async() => {
  console.log(`readyState: '${document.readyState}'`);

  // A.1
  App.onDCL1(payload => console.log(`A.1.| ${payload}`)); // run callback
  // B.1
  App.onDCL2().then(payload => console.log(`B.1.| ${payload}`)); // Promise chain
  // C.1
  let payload = await App.onDCL2(); // await  for Promise. Hint: no 'async' required, since we already return a Promise
  console.log(`C.1.| ${payload}`);


  // have to wait for C.1. (`await`) ....
  // ... comment 2 lines of "C.1" will show 'END' bevor Promise B.1. gets resolved async (~1ms)
  console.log('END 1');

  setTimeout(async() => {
    // dispatch "fake" event in 100ms, (we need to addEventListeners first
    // ... since C.2 has `await` we do this here
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.document.dispatchEvent(new Event("DOMContentLoaded", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      }));
    }, 100);

    // A.2
    App.onDCL1(payload => console.log(`A.2.| ${payload}`)); // run callback
    // B.2
    App.onDCL2().then(payload => console.log(`B.2.| ${payload}`)); // Promise chain
    // C.2
    let payload = await App.onDCL2(); // await  for Promise
    console.log(`C.2.| ${payload}`);

    console.log('END 2');
  }, 300);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use an interval to run the code once the module has loaded:

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(document.readyState!=="loading") {
        clearInterval(interval);
        ... your code here ...
    }
},250)
```