# Why unused import fixes the issue with content loading

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

My project is quite large and I cannot share it for obvious reasons. Project is not even hosted remotely, I only have local server serving me `index.html` file. Server is made with Express.

Slightly simplified, a project is structured like so:

```
 - views
   - view1.js
   - view2.js
   - view3.js
 - index.html
 - services
   - script1.js
   - script2.js
   - script3.js
   - router.js
 - styles
   - style1.css
   - style2.css
 - server.js
```

Project is run as SPA.

When I start the server and the application is loaded, `DOMContentLoaded` event listener is never fired from the `script3.js` file unless I specify any arbitrary unused `import` inside e.g. `script1.js` file, e.g. `import { someFunction } from "../../somescript.js"`. I am quite sure I don't have any circular dependencies. Any time I omit `import`, application doesn't load as expected. Anytime I include the `import` (tried with different imports from totally different scripts), it always works. Keep in mind import is never actually used inside the script, but for some reason it makes my application load properly.

Does anyone have any ideas? Is there some ES6 module detail I am not aware?

Comment: Have you tried putting a simple (test) "DOMContentLoaded" handler in an inline `<script>` block directly in the `index.html` file?

Comment: What does "*DOMContentLoaded event listener is never fired from the script3.js file*" mean? How are you loading the script3 file? How are you listening to the event?

Comment: I've tried now. I put the inline script at the bottom of the body element. Event fires properly regardless of the imports (as expected), however, I cannot run some other imported functions that way.

Comment: @Bergi all scripts are type of module. They are loaded correctly from what I've seen. E.g. script3.js correctly output outside console.log, but console.log inside DOMContentLoaded listener is never fired.

Listener is declared at the top of the module. It is not nested.

Comment: Again, *how* are they loaded? Please share the code. But most likely they simply execute after the `DOMContentLoaded` event, check with [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) at the point where you are installing the listener.

Comment: @Bergi
Only one script is directly included inside `index.html`. Other scripts (including the one that holds listener) are not included in html file at all. No difference if i include them though. I guess its runtime thing and all modules are deferred by default according to standard.

`readyState` (just before listener) says `interactive` when `import` is included, and it says `complete` when `import` is omitted.

Sadly, code is private and I don't really know how to isolate snippets so it makes sense.

Comment: If it says `interactive`, then that's clearly the reason why the event listener doesn't fire afterwards.

Comment: Even though I still don't understand how having unused import in one of my script files helps with mitigating the issue, I decided to remove it cause it is dumb solution. Instead, I fixed the issue by implementing a provided solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61612246/domcontentloaded-never-fires-inside-a-module

It is something Pointy mentioned in the first comment, but I didn't know you could import inline as well (my bad).

Thank you Pointy and Bergi on your help and advices.